# Android, Intellij IDEA. Косячно переименовался пакет, ошибка Error converting bytecode to dex, class name "..." does not match path "..."

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

Доброе время суток.

27 ошибок выглядят примерно так:

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: PARSE ERROR:
class name (com/example/admin/myapplication/BuildConfig) does not match path (nsc/kinetics/cyto/myapplication/BuildConfig.class)
...while parsing "мое имя"/"мое имя"/"мое имя"/myapplication/BuildConfig.class

Я уже давно переименовала пакеты с помощью refractor по этой инструкции http://awesomedevelop.blogspot.ru/2015/01/how-to-change-packagename.html
И думала, что все работает, но это работает почему-то только для API 19 и ниже, а для API 21 и выше выдается ошибка.
Я заметила, что в структуре проекта папка с именем myapplication никак не хочет переименовываться. Она находится по адресу ...\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\folders\1\5\slice_7\"мое имя"\"мое имя"\"мое имя"\myapplication

Я что только не делала -- меняла build.gradle, чистила проект, переименовывала вручную, что нифига не помогало, а пакеты возвращали себе старое имя.
На всякий случай кину манифест и app/gradle.build:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="мое_имя.мое_имя.мое_имя.мое_имя">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

    >
        <activity android:name="мое_имя.мое_имя.мое_имя.мое_имя.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "мое_имя.мое_имя.мое_имя.мое_имя"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'


    }
    dexOptions {

        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. С чем это может быть связано?
Если нужно подробнее, то недавно я уже публиковала эту проблему:

[Error converting bytecode to dex: на API 19 и ниже работает нормально, но на API 21 и выше валится на стадии gradle](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797686/error-converting-bytecode-to-dex-%D0%BD%D0%B0-api-19-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-api)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282899/error-converting-bytecode-to-dex-my-app-works-fine-when-i-run-it-on-api-19-or-l

Comment: мое_имя - это пустышка для вопроса или у вас серьезно так везде .?

Comment: ну конечно вместо мое_имя там стоят нормальные имена пакетов, просто я не считаю уместным их писать:)